# TypeError: set_cookie() got an unexpected keyword argument 'samesite' (flask)

Tags: python, flask

I have tried to run some extensions of flask that provide user management and authentication/login, like flask-admin. The problem is that whenever I try to run one of the examples that will run a simple user login/registration page and then click on login or register button, I always get the following error:

> TypeError: set_cookie() got an unexpected keyword argument 'samesite'

The complete error log reported by Python is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1816, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1833, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2114, in process_response
    self.session_interface.save_session(self, ctx.session, response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 384, in save_session
    samesite=samesite
```

I have looked around but could not find any solution for it. Is there any mismatch between the version of different components that I use? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded to:

```
Flask>=1.0.2
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

And the error went away.  I suspect it is an issue with an older Werkzeug